# Understanding complete linkage

Tags: hierarchical-clustering, scipy

I was trying to understand the [`linkage`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.cluster.hierarchy.linkage.html#scipy-cluster-hierarchy-linkage) function from `scipy` and I was confused with the output for this sample code

```
from scipy.cluster.hierarchy import linkage

X = [[0, 0], [2, 2], [3, 3]]
Z = linkage(X, 'complete')
```

This yields a `Z` as

```
array([[1.        , 2.        , 1.41421356, 2.        ],
       [0.        , 3.        , 4.24264069, 3.        ]])
```

As per the documentation

> method=’complete’ assigns
>
> [image: complete]
>
> for all points   in cluster `u` and in cluster `v`. This is also known
> by the Farthest Point Algorithm or Voor Hees Algorithm.

Why does the `0`th row of `Z` combine clusters `1` and `2` which are separated by a distance of `1.414` when `[0,0]` and `[3,3]` are separated by a distance of `4.24`? Is it that while *creating* clusters, it goes for the minimum Euclidean distance but *how* it calculates the distance between the clusters is controlled by the `linkage` method which would explain the `1`th row entry of `Z` as it now picks up cluster `0` and `3` and the distance between them is calculated as `4.24`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Cluster analysis always combines the closest clusters first. The different linkage methods are ways of determining the distances between clusters. But once those are found, it's closest first.

Complete linkage defines the distance between two clusters as the farthest distance of any points with one in one cluster and the other in the other. OTOH, single linkage defines it as the smallest distance. Other methods do median distance or mean distance or other things.

This can lead to very different patterns.